# File input attachment format for Contact Form plugin

Tags: plugin-contactform, assetfilemodel

Is it possible to specify the file formats for an upload field with the Contact Form?

Is it controlled by the extraAllowedFileExtensions setting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, currently it will allow all file types and does not take the [extraAllowedFileExtensions](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/config-settings#extraAllowedFileExtensions) config setting into account.